# Dyes that can stain oil and water

Tags: organic-chemistry, solubility, surfactants, photochemistry

Is there such a thing as a dye that can stain both oil and water?  In other words, does anyone know of an amphiphilic dye?  Maybe a surfactant that is also a pretty shade of blue?  Or maybe turn one color in oil, but another in water, but stain both well?
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps not a direct answer to your question, but I would imagine that anionic, water-soluble dyes could be transferred into organic solvents by use of a [phase-transfer catalyst](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-transfer_catalyst).

Comment: A napthalimide made with a PEO oligomer amine might split the difference in Day-Glo, doi:10.1016/j.jphotochem.2010.09.002

Answer (score 7):

The diazo dye (**1**), known as **Solvent Yellow 124** or **Somalia Yellow** is soluble in aliphatic hydrocarbons. In the European Community, it is used to mark low-taxed diesel fuel (for heating purposes). In order to prevent its use in cars, samples are acidified. This results in acetal cleavage and protonation of the diazo-fragment, yielding the red, water-soluble iminoquinone species (**2**)

[image: solvent-yellow-124 hydrolysis and protonation]

Since this is probably not exactly what you wanted, what about dyes that exist in a neutral and a zwitterionic form, depending on the polarity of the solvent?

[image: brooker' merocyanine: neutral and zwitterionic form]

**Brooker's merocyanine** is one of the most prominent examples and show strong **solvatochromism**, i.e. the colour changes with the polarity of the solvent